# C# Unsigned bytes Encryption to Java Signed bytes Decryption

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, unsigned, signed

I have an application in C# that encrypt **part of my files** (because they are big files) using RijndaelManaged. So I convert my file to byte arrays and encrypt only a part of it.

Then I want to decrypt the file using Java. So I have to decrypt **only part of the file** (means those bytes) that was encrypted in C#.

Here the problem comes. Because in C# we have **unsigned bytes** and in Java we have **signed bytes**. So my encryption and decryption not working the way I want.

In C# I have joined the encrypted bytes and normal bytes together and saved them with `File.WriteAllBytes`. So I can't use **sbyte** here or I don't know how to do it:

```
byte[] myEncryptedFile = new byte[myFile.Length];
for (long i = 0; i < encryptedBlockBytes.Length; i++)
{
   myEncryptedFile[i] = encryptedBlockBytes[i];
}
for (long i = encryptedBlockBytes.Length; i < myFile.Length; i++)
{
   myEncryptedFile[i] = myFileBytes[i];

}

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\enc_file.big", myEncryptedFile);
```

( And there is an exact same code for decryption in Java )

So my questions are:

- Is there any **WriteAllsBytes** in C#?
- Or can I use **unsigned bytes** in Java?
- Or any other solutions to my problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java may be you can convert it to unsigned

Comment: I've checked that before. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: I don't get this question. If the bytes are used as numbers during mathematical operations then it does matter if the bytes are signed or unsigned. All known symmetric ciphers however treat the bytes as just a set of 8 bits (at least regarding input/output). `RijndaelManaged` does not seem to be an exception to this rule. In other words, you should not have any issue as long as your bytes contain the same bits in the right order.

Comment: @owlstead: For instance if this is my byte array in C#: {200,201,202} and then I encrypt and write it to a file, how Java could decrypt 'the encrypted array' into {200,201,202} when it doesn't have any unsigned byte array?

Comment: Yes, you would get negative values if you would print out the bytes. But print each byte out using `& 0xFF` (which makes it a positive `int` value) and you should get the same values. The question is how you *interpret* the bytes.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But how can I use "cipher.doFinal(myBytes)" in Java? (This is my problem right now)

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11039059/1149773
@Natasha: In brief: Just use it like that.

Comment: Just as you wrote it. If you want to represent `{200, 201, 202}` then write `{(byte)200, (byte)201, (byte)202}`, which does the opposite of `& 0xFF`. Just don't go over 255 of course as those values don't fit into a byte.

Comment: Have you actually tried this in Java, using signed bytes?  Did you get any problems writing the file?  If signs are a problem for you, try examining your data as hex rather than as signed numbers.

Comment: Whether an integer type is signed is only relevant during addition, subtraction, division, and right shift (and of course when converting the number to a string). AES does not use any of these operations, except right shift – but Java provides the `>>>` operator, which performs an *unsigned right shift*.

Comment: @Natasha have we solved your problem by now or are you still unsure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you cannot use unsigned bytes in Java, you may simply ignore the issue.

AES - and all modern symmetric ciphers - operates on bytes, and the input and output have been defined to be bytes (or octets). Input and output have been standardized by NIST and test vectors are available.

If you look at the separate bit content of the bytes then `{200,201,202}` in C# and `{(byte)200, (byte)201, (byte)202}` in Java are identical. This is because Java uses two-complement representation of bytes.

Take the number `200` as integer: this will be `11010000` in binary, representing the number `-56` in Java if used in a (signed) byte in two complements. Now symmetric ciphers will simply transform these bits to another (normally using a full *block* of bits).

Once you have retrieved the answer you will see that they are identical both in C# and Java *when you look at the separate bits*. C# will however interpret those as unsigned values and Java as signed values.

If you want to print out or use these values as signed numbers in Java then you have to convert them to positive signed integers. The way to do this is to use `int p = b & 0xFF`.

This does the following (I'll use the number 200 again):

1. The (negative) byte value is expanded to a signed integer, remembering the sign bit:

   `11010000` becomes `11111111 11111111 11111111 11010000`
2. This value is "masked" with `0xFF` or `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111` by performing the binary AND operator:

   `11111111 11111111 11111111 11010000 & 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11010000`

This value is identical to the value `200` as a signed integer.

Comment: Although I have found the solution using BinaryWriter.Write(SByte) in C#, but your answer is worth to be checked. Thanks for the information.