# C#: Write signed byte array ( sbyte[] ) to a File

Tags: c#, io, binary, arrays, filestream

With `File.WriteAllBytes` we can write byte array into a file like this:

```
byte[] myByteArray;
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\myFile.format", myByteArray);
```

But is there a way to write signed byte array ( **sbyte[]** ) to a file?
Something like this:

```
sbyte[] my_sByteArray;
File.WriteAllsBytes(@"C:\myFile.format", my_sByteArray);
```

For those who want to know the reason that why I want this, please follow **[my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754262/c-sharp-unsigned-bytes-encryption-to-java-signed-bytes-decryption)**.

Comment: BinaryWrite.Write has an overload for this

Comment: If I use BinaryWrite.Write(sbyte) with a ForLoop, does it cover what I wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this:

```
sbyte[] my_sByteArray = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
byte[] my_byteArray = (byte[])my_sByteArray.Cast<byte>();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\myFile.format", my_byteArray); // FE FF 00 01 02
```

Or even this:

```
sbyte[] my_sByteArray = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
byte[] my_byteArray = (byte[])(Array)my_sByteArray;
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\myFile.format", my_byteArray); // FE FF 00 01 02
```

One possible alternative solution is to convert the `sbytes` to `short`'s or `int`'s before writing them to the file. Like this:

```
sbyte[] my_sByteArray = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
byte[] my_byteArray = 
    my_sByteArray.SelectMany(s => BitConverter.GetBytes((short)s)).ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\myFile.format", my_byteArray); 
// FE FF FF FF 00 00 01 00 02 00
```

Of course this doubles (or quadruples if using `int`) the number of bytes you have to write, for very little benefit.

Comment: But again my_byteArray converts all sbytes to bytes and that is not what I wanted as you can see in the Linked question.

Comment: @Natasha They have the same binary representation. `new sbyte[]{ -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 }` will be written out as `FE FF 00 01 02`. The problem in your linked question, as others pointed out, is not in getting C# to write signed bytes to a file (which this accomplishes), it's in interpreting them when you read it back in Java.

Comment: As you can see in comments of the Linked question, how can I use 'cipher.doFinal(myBytes)' in Java? I can't use int[] in Java for the problem.

Comment: @Natasha I'm not a Java developer, so sadly, I can't really answer that. This question was specifically about printing signed bytes in C#, and that's what my answer addresses.

Comment: @Natasha For what it's worth, I've tried to provide another alternative which might be of some use to you. Hope this helps.