# C# MD5 Hashing Is not the same with Java MD5

Tags: java, c#, hash

This is my java code.

```
byte[] bytes = { 0x35, 0x24, 0x76, 0x12 };
  MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  byte[] digest = m.digest(bytes);
```

C#

```
 byte[] bytes = { 0x35, 0x24, 0x76, 0x12 };
 MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
 byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
```

I have noticed that the resulting bytes are different, I am new in java, can someone explain.. thanks..

the result are

c#

```
[  58,  74, 139,   3, 244, 223, 176, 230, 227, 252, 130, 221,  54, 159, 112, 239]
```

java

```
[  58,  74,-117,   3, -12, -33, -80, -26, -29,  -4,-126, -35,  54, -97, 112, -17]
```

Comment: For Java
[58, 74, -117, 3, -12, -33, -80, -26, -29, -4, -126, -35, 54, -97, 112, -17]
For C#

Comment: They are the same ;o)

Comment: For a better understanding read the docs about Java byte type https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can see on the different results that all positive values are the same. Only the negative ones are different. In [.net byte type](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/byte) is unsigned so its range is from 0 to 255. In Java the byte type has a range from -128 to 127. [You can read it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: do this mean that if i use the byte in c# as a key the java wont be able to decrypt it ? bec the produce different . did i hit a limitation of this system?

Comment: Take a look on this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754262/c-sharp-unsigned-bytes-encryption-to-java-signed-bytes-decryption]. Maybe it depens on the used encryption algorithm but i think it will be possible to decrypt something in c# what is encrypted by java application.