# Equivalent GetBytes function in Java like c#

Tags: c#, java, encoding

I have problem with converting string to bytes in Java when I'm porting my C# library to it. It converts the string but it is not the same byte array.

I use this code in C#

```
string input = "Test ěščřžýáíé 1234";
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(input);
```

And code in Java

```
String input = "Test ěščřžýáíé 1234";
String encoding = "UTF8";
byte[] data = input.getBytes(encoding);
```

Lwft one is Java output and right one is C# how to make Java output same as C# one ?

[image]

Comment: It should be "UTF-8" (edit: shouldn't matter -- "UTF8" is an alias)

Comment: Can you try and use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and the appropriate `.getBytes()` method?

Comment: Wait wait wait -- how do you test that the bytes are the same? Don't forget that `byte` in C# is unsigned while it is a _signed_ value in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In likelihood, the byte arrays *are* the same. However, if you're formatting them to a string representation (e.g. to view through a debugger), then they would *appear* different, since the `byte` data type is treated as unsigned in C# (having values `0`–`255`) but signed in Java (values `-128`–`127`). Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11038954/1149773) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11039059/1149773) for an explanation.

**Edit**: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266841/1149773), you can print unsigned values in Java using:

```
byte b = -60;
System.out.println((short)(b & 0xFF));   // output: 196
```

Comment: And is there any way to get in Java unsigned bytes instead signed in C# ?

Comment: @JanSchwar see my answer; but literally, you cannot get "unsigned bytes". Some libraries, like Guava, do provide helpers for such cases however.

Comment: To compare the lists (visually) `for ( byte b : data ) System.out.println(b < 0 ? 256 + b : b);`

Answer (score 2):

These arrays are very probably the same.

You are hit by a big difference between C# and Java: in Java, `byte` is **unsigned**.

In order to dump, try this:

```
public void dumpBytesToStdout(final byte[] array)
{
    for (final byte b: array)
        System.out.printf("%02X\n", b);
}
```

And do an equivalent dump method in C# (no idea how, I don't do C#)

Alternatively, if your dump function involves integer types larger than byte, for instance an int, do:

```
i & 0xff
```

to remove the sign bits. Note that if you cast byte -1, which reads:

```
1111 1111
```

to an int, this will NOT give:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

but:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

ie, the sign bit is "carried" (otherwise, casting would yield int value 255, which is not -1)